# Default Action for Cancel-Dialog in Gedit nearly not visible

Tags: themes, gtk, gedit, accessibility, usability

I am getting older and my eyes see worse.

If I close gedit, I can hardly see the default action which is "Save as..."

[image]

Is there a way to make default actions (in all applications) more visible?

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Ubuntu 18.04 and if you have installed `gnome-tweaks`, you can check out the various themes already available to you. For the purpose of your question, if you select *High Contrast*, you should see something like this:

[image: High Contrast]

It isn't pretty but the contrast is stark.

Another option is to install `materia-gtk-theme` from the repos. With `Materia`, you'll see this:

[image: materia]

When you install `materia-gtk-theme`, you'll also get the dark variant and that looks like this:

[image: Materia-dark]

Of course, you can always search the internet for more themes! The only caution is that you don't install themes that are not compatible with your system's version of *gtk3*. So, probably avoid themes made more than a couple of years ago.

## Edit:

A hack which may work for you is to create the plain text file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` if such a file doesn't already exist and then to edit it to contain the following on a line by itself:

```
* { outline-width: 5px; }
```

You can see the result (with *Materia-light*) in the image below:

[image: using outline-width]

You can change `5px` to whatever you're comfortable with. This hack works with some themes but doesn't work with others such as *Ambiance*.